# Docker failover: Redis, MySQL and Nginx

Tags: mysql, nginx, docker, redis, docker-compose

Currently we have `Redis master` and `Redis slave` containers. `MySQL master` and `MySQL slave` containers. Both replicating.

How would we handle a failure on one of the master containers? Should I be using something like Nginx as a forward proxy to detect connection failures?

Already we do this on our `API` servers and `Web` servers.

Comment: `haproxy` might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the replication of MySQL I suggest configuring MySQL in a master <-> master approach and setup an HAProxy load balancer over them, as eugeneware does in https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-mysql-replication. It is very easy to set up using an HAProxy Docker container.

For Redis it definitely looks like you need Sentinel: http://redis.io/topics/sentinel. In https://hub.docker.com/r/joshula/redis-sentinel/ you can find a docker image for Sentinel.

I don't think using a proxy like Nginx is an appropriate solution for both problems.

Comment: After further investigation i agree. Our API servers now each run in a container with PHP-FPM and Nginx (systemd as well). Load balancing for all services is via HAproxy. tutum/haproxy to be specific